# Can I get the Automatic Daylight Saving Time info from a VM through powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to get a CSV of VMs that have the "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically?" set as off.

I think I can't create a script that search all the VMs in my subscription at once, since the information about the DST is not in the Azure portal. So maybe can I run something on each VM to get the expected result?

Is there any way to get this information using powershell at all?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy script for Windows VMs: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/check-for-daylight-savings-time-by-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this myself, but I think you only have to see if the `DaylightBias` property returned by `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_TimeZone` is anything other than 0

```
Get-VM | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.State -eq 'Running') {
        $tz = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_TimeZone -ComputerName $_.Name
        $dst = if (!$tz.DaylightBias) { 'Off' } else { 'On' }
    }
    else {
        $dst = 'Unknown'
    }
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Computer'           = $_.Name
        'Status'             = $_.State
        'DaylightSavingTime' = $dst
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\VM-DstInfo.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Or perhaps execute cmdlet `Get-TimeZone` on the VM will get you the info you need:

```
Get-VM | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.State -eq 'Running') {
        $tz  = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.Name -ScriptBlock {Get-TimeZone}
        $dst = if (!$tz.SupportsDaylightSavingTime) { 'Off' } else { 'On' }
    }
    else {
        $dst = 'Unknown'
    }
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Computer'           = $_.Name
        'Status'             = $_.State
        'DaylightSavingTime' = $dst
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\VM-DstInfo.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```